# Vector of pair with const member

Tags: c++, vector, language-lawyer

As stated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8467987/2378300) a `std::vector<T>` cannot contain `const T`, or classes with `const`-members. However, this is not the case when `T = std::pair<const int, int>`, as shown below. Why is this the case? How is `std::pair` special?

```
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

struct foo
{
    const int first;
    int second;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::pair<const int, int>> V1;
    V1.resize(3); // This compiles

    std::vector<foo> V2;
    V2.resize(3); // This gives the error listed below
}
```

> error: use of deleted function 'foo::foo()'
>
> note: 'foo::foo()' is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:

Comment: You linked to a Q&A about C++03. Not saying it's necessarily irrelevant, but a lot has been tweaked  in the C++ standard since.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are mixing two things here. The error that you get is due to the implicitly deleted `foo()` default constructor that [`std::vector::resize(size_type count)`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/resize) invokes:

> If the current size is less than `count`,
>   1) additional default-inserted elements are appended

The `std::pair` template has a default constructor, this is why the call to `V1.resize` succeeds. If you provide one for `foo` as well, or allow its implicit generation by in class initialization, e.g.

```
struct foo
{
    const int first = 42;
    int second = 43;
};
```

then

```
std::vector<foo> V2;
V2.resize(3);
```

will happily compile. The operation that won't work out for both `std::pair<const int, int>` and `foo` is *assignment*. This won't compile:

```
V1[0] = std::pair<const int, int>(42, 43); // No way
V2[0] = { 42, 43 }; // Also not ok, can't assign to const data member
```

which doesn't have anything to do with `std::vector`, but with the `const`-qualified data members in both cases.

Comment: Isn't it also related to that fact that in C++03 (the Q&A the OP quoted) the requirements were container-wide, while now they are more member function specific?

Comment: @StoryTeller Good question. Comparing the container requirements between two versions of the standard seems a bit above my pay grade, but I'll try to think about it :)